# javascript working cross-browser locally, but only in Chrome/Firefox when on server?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've been trying to implement this jcrop tutorial

http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/

but in getting the first page even to work, (after the point of selecting a file with the Browse button)  I'm getting strange results that don't add up...  based on the following, I wondered if you could deduce something obvious to check for? (And I guess its jamming on the javascript)

## Does it work?

Chrome:  locally and server
IE       locally but not server
Firefox  locally and server
Safari   not server

I know Chrome is supposed to be more forgiving for html issues, but I don't understand why IE processes my page fine locally, but exact same files and structure it gets stuck on when they're online. (yet Google on any machine runs the pages fine when online)

The interesting thing also is that when I do an exact html copy of the tutorial demo & related files (checking file paths etc) again, the exact tutorial files run fine cross-browser locally, but uploaded to my server and it jams on IE (at least). But runs Chrome.  It should be noted the tutorial demo when hosted on the TUTORIAL website, runs fine cross-browser.

My head is spinning around in circles - especially after replicating the exact tutorial files but on my own server?!  Many thanks!

Comment: What about Firefox? Checked the browser console for errors? What version of IE and jQuery are you using?

Comment: Whats the URL? Look in the F12 JavaScript console. Verify that dependent script resources are present with the correct paths.

Comment: this may be a dumb question, but when you deploy to server, and access it via IE are you in compatibility mode, or vice versa, are you in compatibility mode when debugging and not when deployed?

Comment: Thank you for your help - really appreciated!  

- It works in Firefox on server :)
- I found IE9 fails to run it, but IE11 works on the server finally!
- I'll start using the console to debug when I get issues, sounds very useful
- I've noticed it doesn't work in IE when compatibility mode is switched on
- Ultimately now, this works in latest IE, Firefox, Chrome and (iphone) Safari.  But not Windows Safari (latest).   So looks like my next Nemesis is Safari - which apparently has issues.